# Reference .css and .js files for google chrome in Asp.Net projects

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, razor, layout

Is there any problem if I reference .css and .js with "~/file.ext" for chrome? Because I get some layout errors when I do it this way. Does chrome want it like "../" instead of "~/"? I am developing with Asp.Net Core and I just drag and drop the files from the Solution to the Html to create the references.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when using the standard HTML, CSS, JS if a file that you want to point/reference to is outside of the folder where you're typing in your code then yes, "../" is generally the way to do so.

Try pointing to images or make an external .css and try referencing to it to test it out.

Comment: the files are inside the project folder, in wwwroot folder more specific, and actually the css and js files get called, but with some design errors (only in chrome). One friend of mine found a strange solution for this problem, he referenced the files like this: (in older version of asp.net, not in asp.net core, cuz i tried the same in asp.net core but without success) "../../folder/filename.css"